# a verb to mean to start "not being on speaking terms"

Tags: word-request, verbs

There are many terms describing 'ending a relationship'. I'm looking for a dynamic (not static) verb to stop a not necessarily romantic or sexual relationship but to stop relationship for example with your family members or intimate friends because of a quarrel or disagreement.

> I'm not on speaking terms with my brother.

How do you paraphrase this sentence with an dynamic/active verb?

Comment: Presumably, you are looking for something more specific than *fall out*?

Comment: What do you think @Mick ? Is "fall out" appropriate and common and not weird to use in common conversations?

Comment: I can't really think of anything else to use. Certainly, if you *fall out* with someone, you may no longer be on *speaking terms*. *Fall out* can be used in both everyday and formal English. Of course, there is the abominable *unfriend*.

Comment: So i choose "fall out" to explain that action. It's a little strange why others hasn't mentioned it. I thought the reason is the verb "fall out" isn't accepted and common between natives in their daily conversations. So now it's settled :) :) Tnx @Mick

Answer (score 5):

The phrase that you are looking for may be as simple as [*fall out*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fall-out). I cannot think of anything more specific. Certainly, if you *fall out* with someone, you may no longer be on *speaking terms* with them. The expression can be used in both everyday and formal English.

> **fall out** — phrasal verb with fall
>
> (ARGUE) informal
>
> to argue with someone and stop being friendly with them:
>
> - He left home after falling out with his parents.
> - She'd fallen out with her boyfriend over his ex-girlfriend.

Cambridge Dictionary

Answer (score 3):

Piggy-backing off Andrew's answer, the word *estrange* can be used as a verb, but I don't hear it used that way very often, and it sounds awkward to me when I try to use it that way:

> *He estranged his brother last Christmas after an argument about politics*.

You can look at [this Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=his+estranged%2Che+estranged&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) and see that the adjective form has become much more popular than the verb form over several decades.

However, I looked up the verb *estrange* in the thesaurus, and found a very suitable synonym: ***alienate***.

Unlike *estrange*, writers use *alienate* more often as a verb than as an adjective, [according to the ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=his+alienated%2Che+alienated&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3). So you could say:

> *He alienated his brother last Christmas after an argument about politics*.

According to NOAD, *alienate* is defined as:

> **alienate** (*verb*) cause (someone) to feel isolated or estranged; cause (someone) to become unsympathetic or hostile

Looking up *alienate* in a thesaurus provides some other candidate verbs, such as *divide* (which is fairly common) and *disunite* (not so much so). However, I think *divide* works better in a more passive construct:

> *The brothers were divided last Christmas after an argument about politics*.

(You wouldn't say, "He divided his brother last Christmas..." – at least, I hope the argument wouldn't get that out of hand.)

Comment: Are these forms common in everyday conversations? How do you personally explain that condition when you fight or quarrel with a friend (or your brother) and stop speaking and having relation? @J.R.

Comment: As my answer says, _alienate_ is a good word. It's the best word I can think of that fits the structure of your sentence is used in everyday conversation.

Answer (score 3):

To *shun* means to avoid or refuse to meet with, usually from anger, contempt or other disapproving sentiment. To *spurn* means to reject and is more usually used for romantic relations. To *cut* is a somewhat archaic term that means to express contempt by refusing to acknowledge knowing someone.

None of these is exactly right for your use case though.  To say "I *fell out* with him at Christmas" is a slightly unusual application of the expression, but admirably clear, while retaining a polite ambiguity as to just who is shunning whom.  An American in this context might say, "I *cut off contact* with him".

But, really, I don't think we have an active verb for exactly what you're requesting – I feel pretty sure, given how much people in my family do this, I would have heard such an expression by now if there were one!

Comment: A clear answer. So as an american you would preferably  choose only "I'm not on speaking terms", right ?

Answer (score 1):

The word you're looking for is ["estranged"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/estranged) -- meaning, "to be like a stranger with".  It is used for family or friends who once were close but who now, for some reason, are very distant.

> He has been estranged from his family for decades and never talks about them.

People who are *estranged* can be [*reconciled*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/reconcile).

> The estranged brothers were reconciled by the death of their beloved mother.

Comment: Tnx. It's not a dynamic verb again. Does that mean,there is not a verb in this case not starting with to be verbs?

Answer (score 1):

How about

> He was **[ostracized](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/ostracize)** after behaving badly at Christmas dinner.
>   They are **[ostracizing](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/ostracize)** him after he behaved badly at Christmas dinner.

For your example, you might say

> I am **avoiding** my brother.
>   She is **ignoring** her ex these days.

both imply recent noncommunication.

Comment: Why all the terms are used in adjective form (with to be )? Isn't there any independent verb not accompanied with to be verb? @Peter

Comment: Do these work for you?  "They **ostracized** him after he behaved badly at Christmas dinner", "She began **ignoring** her ex after their fight", "I **avoid** my brother these days", "The church **excommunicated** the cardinal after the scandal".

Comment: If it works for you abseloutely works for me too. Thank you

Comment: Just to clarify, I think _excommunicated_ is a specialized word that works well in the context of the church, but it would be a stretch to use it in conjunction with one's own family.